# Jquery UI dialog cancel button as link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can change JQuery UI Dialog box Cancel button as link at same location after Delete button?

```
 $("#deletedialog").dialog({
    height: 200,
    width: 500,
    buttons: {
        "Delete": {
            text: "Delete",
            class: "btn btn-success",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlpost,
                    type: 'Post',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#' + container).html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        "Cancel": {
            text: "Cancel",
            class: "linkbutton",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most ideal solution, but it'll get the job done

http://jsfiddle.net/1oavLqoo/

I'm simply removing the classes that JUI will add, and leaving your custom class.

```
$(".linkbutton").removeClass("ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only");
```